# cakephp 2.1 fault redirects to another cake instance

Tags: redirect, cakephp-2.1

In my server i have two sites:

opm.asc

dev.opm.asc

While users work on opm.asc, i do my development on dev.opm.asc; when a new version is ready, i simply make a fresh copy of dev.opm.asc as opm.asc, grant rights and we're ready to go.

A few days ago, opm.asc -the production site- started to reflect the code changes on dev.opm.asc folder !. For example, I added some validation to a model on dev.opm.asc and this affected users on opm.asc.

The most evident sign was the login page: I display a version number on this page and users on opm.asc are showing my page as it is on dev.opm.asc, not on opm.asc which is where they are working.

IT and myself went looking for traces on the server logs and htaccess, etc. and found no fault; then we discover the fault must be on the code itself since a copy from a few days ago did not show this behaviour.

Then I tried my most recent code and the issue was gone. However we were unable to detect any suspicious code.

Yesterday it started happening again and I just can't find out what piece of code -if any- can be causing this. I'm using jquery, css, etc. on a unix server while i program in windows netbeans 7.

Any idea on how can this be?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to clean up app/tmp folder in dev before copy to production site.